# Hex number to area

Tags: .net, vb.net, checkbox, hex, bit

I am using VB.net 2012 and I am trying to convert a HEX number to a checkbox.

I have 96 check boxes on a form. d1, d2, d3.. d96 (that is the name of the checkbox's).

I have a HEX number that I need to convert and tick the check box based on it's value.

For Example:
If the HEX value equals 0x5 then checkbox's d1 and d3 need to be ticked only.
If the HEX value equals 0x20 then only checkbox d6 need to be ticked.
If the HEX value equals 0x42400 then checkbox's d10, d13, d18 need to be ticked only.

I haven't been able to work out how to convert this hex value and select the checkbox based on this value.

I then need to do it the other way around. select the check boxes and then click on a button to work out the HEX value based on what has been selected.

Any help would be great.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Presumably you have the number as a string. I suggest processing it a nybble at a time.

Comment: @equisde I have no idea where to start, so hoping to get a few pointers to start.

Comment: Take a look at [Convert.ToInt32(txt, 16)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f1cbtwff.aspx). You have to cut of the 0x though. The other way around would be just [Hex(number)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/963zt96e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Again add the 0x. I guess you can figure out the matching by yourself, if you give it a try.